# Embed Helvetica font on website?

Tags: css, fonts, embed

I want to have a consistent fonts display when user browse my web pages, I'm trying to use font squirrel to convert my fonts into multiple formats but it gives me error somehow...Stated that it is a licensed font.

But I've purchased the font previously, so how do I provide the license for my font in order to let me do the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

depending on where you bought the font you might not have a license to use it on the web.

font web embedding usually requires a special license. ([here](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/buy.html)'s an example with different licensing options for Helvetica Neue).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom font on your page I would suggest having a font file with you page (in the same folder/directory). For example:

```
/folder
    page.html
    font.ttf
```

Then using css @font-face feature:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: font;
    src: url(font.ttf);
}
```

and afterward apply it to any html element

```
body {
    font-family: font;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to extend on Liviu's answer. Helvatica is not a web font. It comes with Mac OS X. So, unless the user has it installed, it won't show. If you are asking if you can embed it or not, the answer is yes, you can embed it. But that is NOT allowed.

If you must use it, go ahead define it as a font family, but also define a fall-back family. Just in case a user doesn't own a mac, they will see the other family font.

Lastly, if you wish to use a web font, maybe you could have a look at Google Web Fonts: https://www.google.com/fonts/ it has many options and it's fairly easy to use. You might even find a font that looks similar to Helvatica or any other fonts you have in mind.

Good Luck!